# ARD - Setting Users Desktop Background to a file stored on clients desktop

Tags: macos, unix, desktop, remote-desktop

Please can someone advise where i may be going wrong. I have copied a file called "ESSADB2020.png" to the clients desktop which succeeded. Now i'm trying to set that file to be the users desktop through a ARD unix command. Here is my code;

```
osascript -e 'tell application "Finder" to set desktop picture to "~/Desktop/ESSADB2020.png" as POSIX file'
```

Which retrieves the following error.

```
33:48: execution error: Finder got an error: AppleEvent handler failed. (-10000)
```

If there's a better way to do then, any suggestions are much appreciated thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can go to System Preferences -> Desktop and Screensaver -> Desktop. There is a pulldown menu that allows user to choose an image for a background. Click on the pulldown menu and select the file you want to use for a desktop picture.

Comment: Thank you for responding but I looking to achieve this on mass across the schools network. Ie sending a png to all staff macbooks via ARD then running the command so it sets it as their background